# Bloomberg VWAP Interval

Tags: excel, bloomberg, vba

[image: Screenshot of Bloomberg]

I am trying to use the open Bloomberg API to gather the VWAP volume on a specific date for a specific time range.

But with this formula:

```
BDP(DHR US Equity; "VWAP_VOLUME"; "VWAP_START_TIME=15:54:00"; "VWAP_END_TIME=15:55:00"; "VWAP_START_DT=20180629"; "VWAP_END_DT=20180629")
```

I get the data `Volume` (3,552), but I want the data from the `VWAP` cell (99,0245).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the field by `EQY_WEIGHTED_AVG_PX` you should get your answer.

There's also `VWAP` for real time updates but I think it only works for the current trading session (not historical data).